# how to calculate the posterior distribution with known mean when variance has exponential distribution?

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, posterior, moments

Here's the problem:

$Y\sim\operatorname{Exp} (1)$, $X|Y\sim N(0,Y)$. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$: $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi y}} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2y} + y}$.

I'm asked to derive the marginal density of $X$. I began with the MGF of $X$ and got $\mathbf{E}\left[e^{tx}\right] = \frac{1}{t^2/2 - 1}$, but I couldn't identify what distribution this is. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: if this is HW please add the `self-study` tag

Comment: it's not HW. it's the review problem for an exam

Comment: The rules for self-study questions apply to old exam problems, too. Please see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info.

Answer (score 3):

According to Wikipedia, the [Laplace Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution) with parameters $\mu$ and $b$ has the following Moment Generating Function:
$$M(t) = \frac{e^{\mu t}}{1 - b^2t^2}$$
Thus if you set $\mu = 0$ and $b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then:
$$M(t) = \frac{1}{1 - t^2/2}$$
However, this differs from your answer by a factor of -1

Comment: oh I think you are right...my calculation of the mgf is wrong.

Comment: That's what I assumed.  Good luck with your exam!